# Starting foreground service from a background thread

Tags: android, react-native, foreground-service

According to the Android docs:

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process;

Does this mean that, even if I have another thread running and I start the service from that thread, it still will run on the UI/Main thread?

For example, I have a React-Native application, and I use a native module to start a foreground service. In React-Native Native native modules run on a separate thread - so will the service here run on the native module's thread or will it still run on the main thread?

Comment: That bit of documentation is awful. Objects, like an instance of some `Service` subclass, do not run on any thread. Methods run on threads.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I just copied that sentence from Google's docs. Makes me wonder, why would they publish something that is misleading...

Answer (score 0):

The`onStartCommand` method of a standard Service (and other methods) will run on the main thread, regardless of what thread has started the service (`context.startService`).